# Clearing the timeout of last created timer object

Tags: javascript

I am new to javascript and playing with the javascript timer example.

I understand that storing the reference of the timer to some variable (`var o=setTimeout(func;1000)`) can make it easy to stop the execution later by calling `clearTimeout(o)`.

But in case when the reference is not stored in the variable, is it still possible to call the `clearTimeout` on the last timer created?

Following is the example where I want to cancel the timer by pressing the stop.

```html
<button onclick="setTimeout(helloWorld, 3000)">Start </button>
<button onclick="clearTimeout()">Stop</button>
<script>
function helloWorld() {
    alert("Hello");
    setTimeout(helloWorld, 3000);
}
</script>
```

Comment: Instead of using inline JavaScript (not really a good idea for readability or maintainability), create handlers in a script tag (or separate file) and store the timeout ID there so you can clear it later?

Comment: This is the only way to clear timer, i mean when you store reference to variable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To elaborate on [the answer provided by Hyyan Abo Fakher](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51311950/1541563), here's a possible implementation of it:

```js
class TimerFactory {
  constructor () {
    this.ids = new Set()
  }

  get last () {
    return [...this.ids.values()].pop()
  }

  setTimeout (fn, ms, ...args) {
    const id = setTimeout(() => {
      this.ids.delete(id)
      fn(...args)
    }, ms)

    this.ids.add(id)
    return id
  }

  clearTimeout (id = this.last) {
    this.ids.delete(id)
    return clearTimeout(id)
  }
}

const timer = new TimerFactory()

function helloWorld () {
  console.log('Hello')
  timer.setTimeout(helloWorld, 1000)
}
```

```html
<button onclick="timer.setTimeout(helloWorld, 1000)">Start </button>
<button onclick="timer.clearTimeout()">Stop</button>
```

**However**, I think it would be much easier and more intuitive to use `setInterval()` here with a guard to prevent multiple intervals from being set:

```js
let intervalId = null

document.querySelector('[data-action="Start"]').addEventListener('click', () => {
  if (intervalId === null) {
    intervalId = setInterval(() => {
      console.log('Hello')
    }, 1000)
  }
})

document.querySelector('[data-action="Stop"]').addEventListener('click', () => {
  clearTimeout(intervalId)
  intervalId = null
})
```

```css
[data-action]:before {
  content: attr(data-action);
}
```

```html
<button data-action="Start"></button>
<button data-action="Stop"></button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, there is no function in JS that allows you to clear a timer without knowing its ID. You will need to keep track of them.

But you can wrap `setTimeout` in another function which keeps track of all created timers.
(for example, save IDs of created timers in an array)
then override `clearTimeout` in another function which accepts an ID of the timer to clear and if the ID is not given clear the last ID from the previous array

```js
const timers = []
const setTimeout = function(func, time) {
  const id = window.setTimeout(() => {

    const index = timers.indexOf(id);
    if (index > -1) timers.splice(index, 1);

    func()
  }, time);

  timers.push(id);
  return id;
}

const clearTimeout = function(id) {
  if (id) {
    window.clearTimeout(id)
    const index = timers.indexOf(id)
    if (index > -1) timers.splice(index, 1);
  } else if (timers.length > 0) {
    const lastTimer = timers[timers.length - 1]
    window.clearTimeout(lastTimer)
    timers.splice(-1, 1)
  }
}

function helloWorld() {
  console.log("Hello");
  setTimeout(helloWorld, 500);
}
```

```html
<button onclick="setTimeout(helloWorld, 3000)">Start </button>
<button onclick="clearTimeout()">Stop</button>
```